# How to Open Any Software using cmd in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, command, windows-10, exe

I will try to open `start sbul.exe` but can't open the Sublime Text Editor in windows 10. so how to open the other software/file using cmd

[image]

Any position in cmd to access another location of software can access ??

[image]

Comment: You will need to add sublime to your environment variables in windows, so it knows where to look for it.

Comment: @escapesequence That means every software path add in environment variable is needed ?

Comment: No, but some software doesn't by default put it-self in these variables. [Useful tutorial for adding sublime](https://scotch.io/tutorials/open-sublime-text-from-the-command-line-using-subl-exe-windows)

Comment: PLEASE SEE MY EDIT QUESTION ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `start explorer
start wmplayer`
If you want to access any other installed software

- goto the installed directory of that software and copy the path.
- goto computer>properties>advance>environment variables> new
- paste it there hit save
- open cmd type `cd your installed directory path`

  start

Comment: Yes.!! but i wish any path to access sublime is possible ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the full path of the `.exe` file. It is most likely in the `Program Files` directory. This means that you will have to run `start C:\\your\path\to\sublime\sbul.exe`. You can check the path by right clicking on the icon, selecting Properties, and looking at the path listed on that window.

Comment: Yes.!! i know that nut i need any shortcut comnand.